Custom API Creating Company but not Users
I am currently building a custom API plugin for a WordPress e-commerce website that should create a company and then a user within the company once it goes through the checkout form. Currently, it is sending a 201 for only the company but not the user, and have been scratching my head as to why.
Here is the function for register company and user that is stored in WordPress and also prepare the data to send to the platform API:
function hr_register_company_and_user($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $billing_company = $order->get_billing_company();
    $firstName = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $lastName = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    $industry = 'Guide';
    $businessType = 'Private';
    $employeeCount = 33;
    $industryClassification = '92 - Public Administration';
    $locationName = 'Primary Location';
    $zip = 90292;

    // Prepare data from the order
    $companyData = [
        'companyName' => $billing_company,
        'displayName' => $billing_company,
        'industry' => $industry,
        'configurationName' => $companyData,
        'businessType' => $businessType,
        'employeeCount' => $employeeCount,
        'industryClassification' => $industryClassification,
        'location' => Array (
            'locationName' => $locationName,
            'zip' => $zip,
        ),
    ];

    // Handle product selection for configurationName
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        if (strpos(strtolower($product->get_name()), 'basic') !== false) {
            $companyData['configurationName'] .= 'HR - Basic;';
        }
        if (strpos(strtolower($product->get_name()), 'essentials') !== false) {
            $companyData['configurationName'] .= 'HR - Essentials;';
        }
    }
    $companyData['configurationName'] = rtrim($companyData['configurationName'], ';');

    $accessToken = get_access_token();
    if (!$accessToken) {
        error_log('Failed to obtain access token for Platform API');
        return;
    }

    // Create company via TM API
    $companyId = create_company($accessToken, $companyData);
    if (!$companyId) {
        error_log('Failed to create company via Platform API');
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta($order_id, 'hrcenteruid', $companyId);

    // Prepare data for user creation
    $userData = [
        // 'user' => array(
            'firstName' => $firstName,
            'lastName' => $lastName,
            'email' => $email,
            'userName' => $email, // Assuming username is the same as email
            'role' => 'Employee', // Specify role if necessary
            'companyName' => $billing_company,
        // )
    ];

    // Create user associated with the company
    $userId = hr_create_user($accessToken, $userData, $companyId);
    if (!hr_create_user($accessToken, $userData, $companyId)) {
        error_log('Failed to create user via Platform API');
    }
}

error_log for user does not show in the debug log.
Function for getting access token:
function get_access_token() {
    $url = 'https://site/v2/oauth/token';
    $credentials = base64_encode(CREDS);
    $body = http_build_query([
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => CLIENTID,
        'client_secret' => CLIENTSECRET,
        'username' => USRNME,
        'password' => PSSWRD,
    ]);

    $args = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $credentials,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
        'body' => $body,
        'method' => 'POST',
    ];

    $response = wp_remote_post($url, $args);
    if (is_wp_error($response) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response) != 200) {
        return false;
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    return $data['access_token'] ?? false;
}

Here are both functions to create company and user in the platform API:
function create_company($accessToken, $companyData) {
    $url = 'https://site/v2/companies?partnerID=369';
    $args = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($companyData),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ];

    $response = wp_remote_request($url, $args);
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('WP_Error in create_company: ' . $response->get_error_message());
        return false;
    }

    $statusCode = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    if ($statusCode != 200) {
        error_log('API message in create_company: HTTP status code ' . $statusCode . '; Response: ' . wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
        return false;
    }

    $body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
    return $body['companyId'] ?? false;

}

function hr_create_user($accessToken, $userData, $companyId) {
    $url = 'https://site/v2/users?partnerID=369';
    $userData['companyId'] = $companyId; // Associate user with the company

    $args = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'body' => json_encode($userData),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ];

    $response = wp_remote_request($url, $args);
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('WP_Error in create_user: ' . $response->get_error_message());
        return false;
    }

    $statusCode = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    if ($statusCode != 200) {
        error_log('API message in create_user: HTTP status code ' . $statusCode . '; Response: ' . wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
        return false;
    }

    $body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
    return $data['userId'] ?? false;

}

Would appreciate help or insight

When creating company: $body = json_decode(...); return $body[...]. When creating user: $body = json_decode(...); return $data[...] . Shouldn't the last one be return $body[...]? As far as I can tell $data[...] is not defined.

@FiddlingAway had it with body and changed it to data to see if any changes but nothing happened. Forgot to change it back

If you want to create one user - then why are you calling hr_create_user($accessToken, $userData, $companyId) twice? For the company, you did $companyId = create_company(...); if (!$companyId) { ... } - but for the user, you are doing $userId = hr_create_user(...); if (!hr_create_user(...)) {

What happens if, temporarily, you comment out everything in your hr_create_user, and just put a single echo 'test'? Does it print out anywhere? If it doesn't, the initial problem is not with your function. Also, regarding $body vs $data - shouldn't it be $userData then?

@FiddlingAway tried to see if I could get any message in the error log but I only see the 201 response when I create the company. It's like the create_user function is never touched.

What happens if you add one echo before update_post_meta($order_id, 'hrcenteruid', $companyId);, and the other echo after it? Are they both executed?
